# How to use setTimeout on the socket?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I using node.js and when I receive a request from client I call `setTimeout` function:

```
req.connection.setTimeout(60 * 1000, null);  // throws exception
```

Exception:

```
 Server Internal error TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received null
    at Socket.setStreamTimeout [as setTimeout] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:249:15)
```

What is wrong with this function? This function always calling successfully.

Comment: did you try to remove the null? it says that you are sending null instead of a callback (as its an optional) try removing the null parameter.

Comment: FYI request.connection seems to be deprecated.  (https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_connection) The documentation also suggests calling setTimeout on request itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a callback function if timeout occours

```
req.connection.setTimeout(60 * 1000, function(){
     //What to do if timeout
});  // throws exception
```

Or you shoul duse function without callback parameter:

```
request.setTimeout(6000);
```

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback